# Race condition with a static variable in a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following function:

```cpp
int helper(int id) {
  static std::map<int,int>* lookup_table = new std::map<int,int>();

  // Modify lookup_table

  return (it == lookup_table->end()) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

`helper` is called in multiple threads. What is the way to prevent a race condition for `lookup_table`?

Would this be sufficient?

```cpp
static std::mutex helper_lock;

int helper(int id) {
  static std::map<int,int>* lookup_table = new std::map<int,int>();

  helper_lock.lock();
  // Modify lookup_table
  helper_lock.unlock();

  return (it == lookup_table->end()) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write idiomatic C++ code? Just use a lock class.

Comment: Wait... I see the modification's what's killing you. Is the modification done every time? Side question: Why is `lookup_table` being dynamically allocated? That's a very unusual (and often bad) choice for a library container. Part of their job is to protect you from manual memory management .

Comment: Yes, you need a mutex to control access to the static variable. And, no, you do not need it to be a pointer, and allocated with `new`. That accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever. `static std::map<int,int> lookup_table;` works just as well, and saves a lot of wear and tear on your suffering keyboard. Finally, use a lock guard, instead of explicitly locking/unlocking the mutex. This is a guaranteed, and cost-free way to avoid writing a pile of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will NOT be sufficient. Modifications to an STL container have the potential to invalidate its iterators, so the comparison to `lookup_table.end()` at the end of the function might be invalidated if another thread is modifying the table.

The easy solution is to only unlock after the comparison is done. (note that I'm using `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` to do the locking - lock is released when the `unique_lock` goes out of scope

```
static std::mutex helper_lock;

int helper(int id) {
  static std::map<int,int>* lookup_table = new std::map<int,int>();

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(helper_lock);
  // Modify lookup_table
  // explicit unlock is not required, lock is released when lock is destroyed

  return (it == lookup_table->end()) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

A more complicated solution is to use a `shared_mutex` that allows a read/write lock. This is likely what you want anyway, since certainly you have processes that are reading the lookup table? You can apply the read-lock before the `end()` iterator is read and dereferenced. Multiple threads will be able to read the data at once, but none are allowed to write until all readers are released.

```
static std::shared_mutex helper_lock;

int helper(int id) {
  static std::map<int,int>* lookup_table = new std::map<int,int>();

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(helper_lock);
    // Modify lookup_table
    // explicit unlock is not required, lock is released when lock is destroyed
  }

  // acquire read-only lock, but not if any thread holds a unique_lock
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(helper_lock);
  return (it == lookup_table->end()) ? -1 : 0;
}
```